# tmux behave differently between the command lines and equivalent config file (.tmux.conf)

Tags: tmux

tmux behave differently between the command lines and equivalent config file (.tmux.conf)

command line:

```
bash$ tmux new \; split-window -h \;
```

config file (.tmux.conf), (and then, in the command line, we just type 'tmux')

```
new
split-window -h
```

The command line version nicely shows me a split window at the startup, and it creates only one session.  However, the config file version behave differently:

- It creates 2 sessions, with session name "0" and "1" rather than just one seesion.
- Session "0" has the split windows, identical to what I saw in the command line version.
- Session "1" has a single full window.
- It stops at session "1".

So, in the config file version, I finally reach the session "1" on the screen.  If I do an 'exit', and then attach session 0, then, it goes to session "0" with the same results as the command line version.

If, alternatively, the config file contains only the split line:

```
split-window -h
```

then when 'tmux' is typed, it shows an error message at the startup:

```
.tmux.conf:1: no current target
```

And no split windows (since the split window command fails: As we can see, it complains the 1st line of the configuration to have no current target.)

Apparently, command line version is what I want/need.

What's wrong with the config file version?

Comment: The reason why it creates two sessions with tmux was discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464015/new-session-in-tmux-config-starts-two-sessions (need to see source or logs to confirm this). As for `split-window -h` failing, it needs a target to split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the `tmux` command you manually type after editing `.tmux.conf`.

Many issues with tmux become more understandable when you realize and remember the tmux server and each tmux client are separate processes. In some circumstances a client starts a server. `.tmux.conf` is for the server, not for clients.

`tmux` without arguments behaves like `tmux new-session` aka `tmux new`. It starts a tmux server if needed. When a tmux server starts, it parses `.tmux.conf` before handling requests from tmux clients.

So if there is no server already running, your sole `tmux` creates a tmux server and it executes:

```
new-session      # because of .tmux.conf
split-window -h  # because of .tmux.conf
new-session      # because this is the request from your client
```

Your client ends up attached to the session created with the last [`new-session`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#new-session), the one it implicitly requested.

If you want your client to attach to an already created session, use `tmux attach-session` aka `tmux attach` or `tmux a`. Note in case there is no tmux server yet, `attach-session` will try to create it and the session your `.tmux.conf` will create will count as "already created" when the request from the client is finally handled. This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#attach-session):

> If no server is started, `attach-session` will attempt to start it; this will fail unless sessions are created in the configuration file.

With `.tmux.conf` in question, you need `tmux a` (not just `tmux`) to attach to the session created from within the file. Note if the tmux server already exists, it won't parse `.tmux.conf` again, your `tmux a` will try to attach to some existing session (if any).

Some users (including me) prefer to go back to an existing session, so they use `tmux new-session -A` or `tmux a || tmux` in their shells. These commands work fine with your `.tmux.conf`.

If you want `split-window -h` to run for any newly created session then a hook like this is the way:

```
set-hook -g session-created 'split-window -h'
```

(it's a tmux command, from a shell it will be `tmux set-hook …`).